# How should questions cross-posted on Ask Ubuntu be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions, ubuntu, cross-posting

As a matter of reference, I would like to know how to handle a question that has been cross-posted on Ask Ubuntu as well?

Is flagging them for closure the right thing to do? Or should I just comment on the question with the cross posted link?

Or perhaps, I should do the above in Ask Ubuntu instead?

---

Stack Exchange's general guidance on cross-posting:

- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We [ask people not to cross-post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting), not that it helps much. If it's posted on both sites, flag it here with a link to the other site's version. If we think it's way better here we'll ask the other site to close their version, but usually we close ours and tell the asker they need to pick one site